# Is it possible for us to create an app on our azure and can be shared with others to use?

Tags: azure-active-directory

We are trying to integrate Onedrive with a WebApplication. Intent is to get the content from Onedrive into WebApplication on any event.

We are able to integrate and using the "APP Register" in Azure Active Directory and configuring with Graph API for delegation and then using the client id, client secret and tenant id from WebApplication.

Here, I would like to understand, Is it possible for us to create an app on our azure subscription and have a way for others (other companies/clients) to install it on their azure system using OAuth process in order to avoid any creation of app and sharing other details.

Please let me know if the query is clear or not. If not, I will explain more in detail.

Thanks
Sakti

Comment: If you have any questions, I will answer you as soon as possible.

Comment: We could see the APP created in CompanyA Azure under CompanyB Azure Enterprise Applications.To integrate the Onedrive,From WebAPP provided the ClientID/ClientSecret and TenantID of CompanyA, we provided the CompanyB details to connect to Onedrive.Asked for consent and accepted it gave AADSTS50020: User account 'X@X.onmicrosoft.com' from identity provider 'sts.windows.net/a3750407-35a9-4274-a3f3-52d7e6f9cf0b' does not exist in tenant 'xx.com' and cannot access the application'tenantid' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can share your application with other organizations, you only need to [change your application to a multi-tenant application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#update-registration-to-be-multi-tenant), because changing the application to multi-tenant application allows any tenant to log in.

Next, you need to request the consent of the administrators of other organization tenants. You can send the login request URL: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Other company tenant_id}/adminconsent?client_id={client-id}`. After the administrator consent, it will be added to other organization tenants as an enterprise application in.

However, you need to note that after sharing your application, the permissions granted to it in the original tenant will not exist. If you need the application to access the resources of other company tenants, you must request the other company's IT to grant similar access permissions.